# Is the category of pure Hodge structures abelian semi-simple?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hodge-theory, hodge-structure

Apologies if the question in the title is too elementary.

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42006/on-polarized-pure-hodge-structures?rq=1